# Powershell try-catch...else?

Tags: powershell, try-catch

I understand try-catch-finally in Powershell, but is there something similar to Python's 'else' clause, in which code runs only if there is not an error?

I'm writing a script that uses invoke-webRequest on a site that goes down frequently. I use try-catch to catch HTTP errors. 
I also want a block of code to run only if the invoke-webRequest command completes successfully.

```
try{
    invoke-WebRequest -URI 'http://flakywebsite.com/site1' -Method GET
    invoke-WebRequest -URI 'http://flakywebsite.com/site2' -Method GET
    invoke-WebRequest -URI 'http://flakywebsite.com/site3' -Method GET
    }
catch{
    "This line will execute only if there is an error in the try block"
    }
else{
    "This line will execute only if there is NOT an error in the try block"
    }
finally{
    "This code will run regardless of whether there is or is not an error in the try block."
    }
```

I have this workaround. It uses the catch block to append a notice to the $Error variable:

```
try{
    invoke-WebRequest -URI 'http://flakywebsite.com/site1' -Method GET
    invoke-WebRequest -URI 'http://flakywebsite.com/site2' -Method GET
    invoke-WebRequest -URI 'http://flakywebsite.com/site3' -Method GET
    }
catch{
    $Error.add("An error occurred in the try loop."}
    }
if($Error[-1] -ne "An error occurred in the try loop."){
    "This code will run only if there is NOT an error in the try block.
    }
```

This works, but it's awfully ugly. Is there a better way to do this in Powershell?

Comment: Maybe you can use `if(!$Error){ "An error didn't occur" }`.

Comment: Any error occuring in `Invoke-WebRequest` should (depending on your `$ErrorActionPreference` ofc) trigger the switch to `catch` block, so why don't you just put the code from `else` block below `Invoke-WebRequest`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, as of v7, PowerShell unfortunately does *not* offer a Python-like `else` clause as part of a `try` / `catch` statement.

- You could create a feature request in the [PowerShell Core GitHub repository](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues).

---

One option is to **place the only-if-not caught code at the bottom of your `try` block**, after the commands that may fail - see [Zafer Balkan's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58347098/45375).

**If that is undesirable**, I suggest the following idiom as a **workaround**:

```
# Make sure that even normally non-terminating errors trigger the
# `catch` block below.
# Note that the *first* error that occurs in the `try` block
# will jump to the `catch` block right away - subsequent commands won't execute.
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'

# Save the count of errors currently recorded in the automatic $Errors collection.
$errCountBefore = $Error.Count

try {

    invoke-WebRequest -URI 'http://flakywebsite.com/site1' -Method GET
    invoke-WebRequest -URI 'http://flakywebsite.com/site2' -Method GET
    invoke-WebRequest -URI 'http://flakywebsite.com/site3' -Method GET

}
catch {
    # Write a custom error to the $Error collection, as the *first* 
    # (most recent) item.
    # Note: If you want the error to also *display*, use `-ErrorAction Continue`.
    Write-Error -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue "An error occurred in the try loop: $_"
}

if ($errCountBefore -eq $Error.Count) { # No errors occurred.
  "This code will run only if there is NOT an error in the try block."
}
```

Note: **If you don't write an error in your `catch` block, use a custom `[bool]` variable such as `$caught`** that you set to `$true` in your `catch` block, and then test for `if (-not $caught)`.

---

As for **what you tried**:

> `$Error.add("An error occurred in the try loop."}`

**You shouldn't write *directly* to `$Error`** (which makes the following points moot: don't add *strings* and don't *append* to the collection of errors it stores) for the following reasons:

**`$Error` is a so-called [*automatic variable*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables)** in PowerShell, which generally means that **PowerShell *itself* manages it**, and user code shouldn't modify it directly.

The only exception with respect to `$Error` is that you may want to *clear* the collection of errors that have accumulated in the session so far, using `$Error.Clear()`

Otherwise, PowerShell manages `$Error` as follows:

- Any error is automatically logged in `$Error`, in *reverse* chronological order (most recent one first).

  - The only exceptions are commands that are invoked with `-ErrorAction Ignore` and stderr output from *external programs*.
- `$Error` contains only *error-record objects* (instances of type `System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord`) that provide structured, detailed information about each error.

Therefore, **all your code needs to do in order to record errors in `$Error` is to either write an error to the error stream with `Write-Error`, or to throw a script-terminating error with the `Throw` statement** - PowerShell will wrap each error in a `System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord` instance, if necessary, and prepend to `$Error` in reverse chronological order.

Answer (score 2):

Well, in your try-catch you have added many different things. The best practices recommend one try block for each of your `Invoke-Request` commands, since you cannot get which of the sites created the error. But you can just add the line below your code.

```
try{
    invoke-WebRequest -URI 'http://flakywebsite.com/site1' -Method GET
    invoke-WebRequest -URI 'http://flakywebsite.com/site2' -Method GET
    invoke-WebRequest -URI 'http://flakywebsite.com/site3' -Method GET
    "This line will execute only if there is NOT an error in the try block"
    }
catch{
    "This line will execute only if there is an error in the try block"
    }
finally{
    "This code will run regardless of whether there is or is not an error in the try block."
    }
```